# limit UIDs to one category (delete all other categories per user)

Tags: sql, oracle

I have the following generated table (denormalized) :

```
UID (int)  | CATEGORY(int) | product_title (varchar)
```

the data looks like this :

```
1 | 1 | title1
1 | 1 | title2
1 | 2 | title3
1 | 2 | title4
2 | 1 | title2
2 | 2 | title4
.
.
.
```

Is it possible to delete all (other) categories (leave the user with one category only and delete the rest) ?
using one query in ORACLE ?

so the data will become like :

```
1 | 1 | title1
1 | 1 | title2
2 | 5 | title5
2 | 5 | title6
.
.
.
```

so every UID will have only one category with multiple titles ? just discard n-1 categories per user ?

Thanks

Comment: Do you care which categories you keep and which you discard?  If so, what are your criteria?

Comment: no , i just need to end up with [any] one category per user , with at least 4 titles if possible (or exactly 4 titles) .

Comment: for the titles thing , the database already is checked while creating that it have at least 4 titles per customer per category

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This will do:

```
DELETE Table1 
WHERE 
("UID", CATEGORY) IN
(SELECT "UID", CATEGORY FROM
 (
  select "UID", CATEGORY,
  RANK() OVER(PARTITION BY "UID" ORDER BY CATEGORY) rk
  FROM Table1
 ) t 
 WHERE t.rk > 1
);
```

[SQL Fiddle](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!4/e50a4/23)